# Aria Templates - Form Submission Issues

Tags: javascript, ariatemplates

I am trying to submit an aria template form http://ariatemplates.com/,the submission is done to a Spring MVC controller/servlet.

The form is getting submitted all right but i am not able to get the values of the aria elements like date picker,text box etc in the controller.
`Request.getParameter` is of no use.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Here is my sample tpl file,js file and the Spring Controller.

**TPL File**

```
    {Template {
    $classpath:'view.Turnover',
    $hasScript : true
}}
  {macro main()}
  <form action="test.do" method="POST" id="turnoverform">
  <div style="float:left;padding-top: 3em;padding-bottom: 3em;padding-right: 3em;">
    {@aria:Div {
       sclass : "basic",
       width : 740,
       height : 300
       }}

        <p style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: medium;">Create Turnover Report</p>
        <hr />

        {@aria:DatePicker {
            label: " begin date:",
            labelWidth:190,
            width:330,
            helptext:"Type date or select",

        }/}
        {@aria:DatePicker {
            margins:"x x x 20",
            label: "end date:",
            labelWidth:190,
            helptext:"Type date or select",
            width:330,

        }/}
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        {@aria:TextField {
          label : "User id",
          labelPos : "left",
          helptext : "ID",
          width : 250,
          block : true,
          labelWidth : 80,
          bind : {
            "value" : {
              inside : data,
              to : 'value' }
          }
    }/}
    <br />


   {/@aria:Div}
   <br />
   {@aria:IconButton {
      icon: "std:confirm",
      label:"Create",
      width : 300,
      tooltip : "Click on this to create a Report",
      block: true,
      onclick : {
        fn : buttonClick
      }
    } /}
  </div>
  </form> 
 {/macro}
{/Template}
```

Javascript File :

```
 Aria.tplScriptDefinition({
  $classpath : "view.TurnoverScript",
  $prototype : {
    /**
     * Callback for the click event on the first button.
     * @param {aria.DomEvent} evt Click event
     */
    buttonClick : function (evt) {


      aria.core.IO.asyncFormSubmit({
          formId : "turnoverform",
          callback : {
            fn : this.onSuccess,
            onerror : this.onError,
            scope : this
          }
        });
    },

    onSuccess : function (evt, args) {


        alert("The Template has been created");
        //this.$json.setValue(["view:Dialog"], "dialogOpen", true);

      },



      onError : function (evt, args) {


          alert("The Template has not been created due to some Error");

        }
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you post a code sample please? How do you do the submit? Does [this](http://ariatemplates.com/usermanual/Form_Submissions) help?

Comment: @scenario Already had a look at this and followed it but does not really solve my problem. I have attached the sample code for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Aria Templates you don't work normally with DOM elements but with the data model.

The way to achieve what you want is to bind those values to the datamodel using the `bind` property

```
{@aria:DatePicker {
    label: " begin date:",
    labelWidth:190,
    width:330,
    helptext:"Type date or select",
    bind : {
        value : {
            inside : data,
            to : "begin_date"
        }
    }
}/}
```

Your datamodel would now contain those values, try to modify those values and see the content of `this.data` in your template script.

To submit the data you have two options,

- Template Script through [aria.core.Io.asyncRequest](http://ariatemplates.com/aria/guide/apps/apidocs/#aria.core.IO%3aasyncRequest%3amethod) (or maybe the RequestMgr, depending on your application complexity).
  This method takes a `data` string that in case of `POST` requests is the message body. It has to be a string so you can use `aria.utils.json.JsonSerializer.serialize()` to convert your datamodel into a string.

  aria.utils.json.JsonSerializer.serialize(this.data, config)

In the previous snippet of code `config` is optional, if provided it should match this [bean](http://ariatemplates.com/aria/guide/apps/apidocs/#aria.utils.json.JsonSerializerBeans%3aJsonSerializeOptions).

- Module controller through [submitJsonRequest](http://ariatemplates.com/aria/guide/apps/apidocs/#aria.templates.ModuleCtrl%3asubmitJsonRequest%3amethod)
  The good thing about using a controller is that you separate the logic of connecting to a server from the template and that you can send directly an object as data, serialization is done internally.
  The drawback is that you'll probably have to configure your [UrlService](http://ariatemplates.com/aria/guide/apps/apidocs/#aria.modules.urlService.environment.UrlServiceCfgBeans%3aAppCfg) to convert actions to actual URL. Few more info [here](http://ariatemplates.com/usermanual/URL_handling#Server_requests_URL_handling)